# What can cause the local server to display "Index of /" instead of the wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, local, mamp

When developing a wordpress site on a localhost using MAMP, all I can see is an "Index of/" text and the files I have in my root folder.

I expected to see a local version of a fully functioning wordpress site.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could it be tat your index.php file is missing?
OR if that file exists in the public_html folder- are it’s permissions are being changed?  Just check

Comment: The index.php fiile can be found from the folder called "public". How am I able to check the second option you suggested?

Comment: I am familiar with the LAMP stack - for your stack , try [https://www.google.com/search?q=checking+file+permissions+mamp&oq=checking+file+permissions+mamp&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.8383j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8]